# What does RED text mean in the Firebug net tab?

Tags: firebug

I can't seem to find any help on this but under the Net tab in Firebug, one of my sites is showing red highlighted items.  Unfortunately the site is protected right now so I can't post the link.

[image: Firebug]

Can anyone explain what this means?

Comment: They look to be files that took a longer time to load than the others... no idea other than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ordinarily it indicates a 404 error or some other error, but here you have a 200 status. Use the plus button to expand and look at the response headers. What do they say?

**Edit:** I checked the Firebug source. It definitely means their was a response header in the 400 or 500 range.

Why do you have a 200 OK header, also? I couldn't tell you. I can say that it's based on more than just the response headers looking at the logic in FB. However, I'm not that familiar with it (first time that I've looked at firebug's source).

If you're very curious about the red AND the 200 OK, check out what you have under the plus button. If that doesn't answer your question (do you have a page but maybe it's a 404 page?), fire up a packet sniffer to see in full detail what happens after the initial error header.

Comment: Here's a quick follow up showing what's in the Headers tab for a red image with a 200 OK response:
http://imgur.com/VEmLk.gif

The headers don't appear to have anything strange going on but I could be missing something.  If you notice anything out of place in the headers let me know, I'm just curious about the red flag.

Comment: Hmm ... don't see anything unusual. I think you'll have to use a packet sniffer to get more detail. FB is great, but to see all the headers for all the requests, you'll have to use something els. It definitely at received at least one response header in the 400/500 range.

Comment: for all the late comers: this is a [fixed] bug: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1491

Answer (score 3):

There is some error (usually 404 - the resouce cannot be found), however, your browser might be picking them up from somewhere else, like the cache on your proxy?

[edit]
Turns out this is probably a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1491)

Answer (score 3):

I just had this happen (red text and empty response in the Firebug Net tab, but status of 200 OK). The HTTP call in question, for me, was an AJAX call. Turns out my current page was MYSITE.com and my XMLHttpRequest was going to www.MYSITE.com (note the "www.") . When I included the "www." on my page's URL, the text was black, the response was not empty, and more importantly, the page worked correctly.

Comment: from same server I moved html directory from Apache Web Svr to Tomcat where Servlet was located. Works now.

Answer (score 2):

This also happens when your request is stopped.

It is a common issue with Firefox when you want to send an Ajax request on ESC key press.

To avoid this problem, you can add a small delay:

```
  function callOnEscPress(e){
    if (e.keyCode == Event.KEY_ESC){
      setTimeout(function(){new Ajax.Request(*your_params*)},100);
      Event.stopObserving(document,'keydown', callOnEscPress);
    }
  }
  Event.observe(document,'keydown', callOnEscPress)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue today. The response came back 200 (ok), but not the data. The same request worked in IE after displaying a security pop up (site is accessing information which is not under its control), so I guess it could be cross-domain scripting related.